# How to avoid using a return statement in a for-in loop?

Tags: python, json, django, django-views, for-in-loop

My view below is only going through one iteration cycle and then breaking out the loop. I know that it's probably because of the return statement in this line: `return JsonResponse([post.serialize() for post in posts], safe=False)` but how can I avoid this?

I tried changing the return statement to a print statement instead but then I get a ValueError:
`The view network.views.followingPosts didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.`

Just before the `except` statement I tried putting a continue there but this had no effect.

I'm not really sure how to fix this. Any ideas?

```
def followingPosts(request, user_username):
    try:
        user_profile = get_object_or_404(User, username=user_username)
        following_users = user_profile.get_following()
        for person in following_users:
            posts = Post.objects.filter(creator=person)
    except Profile.DoesNotExist:
        return JsonResponse({"error": "No user found."}, status=404)

    if request.method == "GET":
        return JsonResponse([post.serialize() for post in posts], safe=False)
    
    else:
        return JsonResponse({
            "error": "GET request required."
        }, status=400)
```

Comment: What makes you think that your code is `breaking out the loop`? It can't be because of an exception. So I think it is completing the loop.

Comment: you are overwriting the variable posts. It should be a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @quamrana, I think that the loop is implemented well, except that you store posts only for the last loop run. Here is the correction:

```
def followingPosts(request, user_username):
    try:
        user_profile = get_object_or_404(User, username=user_username)
        following_users = user_profile.get_following()
        posts = list()
        for person in following_users:
            posts += Post.objects.filter(creator=person)
    except Profile.DoesNotExist:
        return JsonResponse({"error": "No user found."}, status=404)

    if request.method == "GET":
        return JsonResponse([post.serialize() for post in posts], safe=False)
    
    else:
        return JsonResponse({
            "error": "GET request required."
        }, status=400)
```

Also, it is a good habit to keep a single line in the try-clause. Therefore, what about

```
def followingPosts(request, user_username):
    try:
        user_profile = get_object_or_404(User, username=user_username)
    except Profile.DoesNotExist:
        return JsonResponse({"error": "No user found."}, status=404)

    if request.method == "GET":
        following_users = user_profile.get_following()
        posts = list()
        for person in following_users:
            posts += Post.objects.filter(creator=person)
        return JsonResponse([post.serialize() for post in posts], safe=False)
    
    else:
        return JsonResponse({
            "error": "GET request required."
        }, status=400)
```

Comment: Could the generation of `posts` be a list comprehension?

Comment: Thank you Kate, this has worked! I was thinking I needed to implement a list function but I wasn't quite sure how and thank you for the additional tip, I have made the change and will keep that in mind.